# Eigenspace and structured matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normal-distribution, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

I have to design a matrix A that solves a linear system:

$y = A x$

The requirement is that A is an RBF kernel, i.e., it has the following structure:

$ a_{ij} = \alpha \exp\left (\frac{-d_{ij}^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$, where d is the distance between each element in the matrix.

My first insight was:

Given that V is the eigenbasis (orthogonal eigenvectors for a fixed $\sigma$ and $\alpha$) of A.
Then, $A = V diag(e) V^{-1}$, where vector e contains all the eigenvalues of A.

The problem simplifies to

$y = V diag (V^{-1} x) e  $

So, for a given $\sigma$ and $alpha$, I can apply least squares to find the eigenvalues e:

$ e = V diag (V^{-1} x) \backslash y  $

By finding the eigenvalues, I can then backengineer as $A = V diag (e) V^{-1}$

My question is: Will this procedure result in a RBF kernel A?
A linear combination of the eigenbasis of a RBF kernel does result in a RBF kernel?

Is there a way to perform such least squares that would garantee the structure of matrix A?

Best.

Best.